# R- Remove rows based on condition across some columns

Tags: r, conditional-statements, rows

I have a data frame like this :

[image]

I want to remove rows which have values = 0 in those columns which are "numeric". I tried some functions but returned to me error o dind't remove anything be cause not the entire row is = 0.  Summarizing, i need to remove the rows which are equals to 0 on the colums that have a numeric class( i.e from sales month to expected sales,). How i could do this???(below attach the result i expect)

[image]

PD: If I could do it with some function that allows me to put the number of the column instead of the name, it would be great!

Answer (score 0):

Here a simple solution with `lapply`.

```
set.seed(5)
df <- data.frame(a=1:10,b=letters[1:10],x=sample(0:5,5,replace = T),y=sample(c(0,10,20,30,40,50),5,replace = T))
df <-df[!unlist(lapply(1:nrow(df), function(i) {
  any(df[i, ] == 0)
})), ]
```

Comment: Hi Elia! Thanks for your answer.

It's weird, but, when i use the code that you wrote, the dataframe stills equal, i.e, i look into the enviroment and see the same quantity of rows.

Comment: you have to assign the operation to a new variable or overwrite the existing data.frame. I edited my answer